# Is it possible (or desirable) for a function to return a vector<&str> in rust

Tags: string, vector, rust, iterator

Suppose I have this function

`fn f() -> std::io::Result<Vec<String>> {`

As far as I understand, the vector must have type `Vec<String>`, and not `Vec<&str>`, as the thing referenced would go out of scope at the end of the function, unless I was referencing something outside the function, or borrowing and returning that thing. So `Vec<String>`.

But suppose I want to `collect` some things in this here vector `v`:

`let v: Vec<&str> = contents.split(',').collect();`

where `split` will return an iterator over `&str`, which we collect into a vector with `collect` (moving slow, I'm a bit new in the language).

But I'm pretty sure I don't want that `&str`, and I should be able to just plug a function between `collect` and `split` to convert my `&str` iterator to a `String` iterator, and then collect, but I'm not finding a way to do that.

Comment: TL;DR: add `.map(String::from)` before `.collect()`

Comment: Clarity! what fresh hell is this? thanks both